# GCM unable to start manual registration

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

in [this example](http://developer.android.com/guide/google/gcm/gcm.html#handling_intents), a broadcast receiver starts intent service.
in the IntentService instance it starts a method called runIntentInService, this method inits a PowerManager.WakeLock object, than start the service.

now, when I manually starts the registration process (from mainActivity) with:

```
    Intent registrationIntent = new Intent("com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTER");
    // sets the app name in the intent
    registrationIntent.putExtra("app", PendingIntent.getBroadcast(mainActivity.this, 0, new Intent(), 0));
    registrationIntent.putExtra("sender", _senderID);
    startService(registrationIntent);
```

in the IntentService, the object of PowerManager.WakeLock has not initialize yet, so it null.

I use [this code](http://developer.android.com/guide/google/gcm/gcm.html#registering) to register from the mainActivity.
should I use [the following](http://developer.android.com/guide/google/gcm/gs.html#android-app) instead?

```
GCMRegistrar.checkDevice(this);
GCMRegistrar.checkManifest(this);
final String regId = GCMRegistrar.getRegistrationId(this);
if (regId.equals("")) {
  GCMRegistrar.register(this, SENDER_ID);
} else {
  Log.v(TAG, "Already registered");
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

GCMRegistrar is just a helper class that does exactly the same thing that you have mentioned, i.e. send register intents etc.
So there is no need to change the code.

Comment: finaly i used the demo android gcm client and it works. now only has to deal with server